# Oracle Apex - Master Detail - How to add another report region using the master detail datepicker

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a *Master Detail** report page created using the **App Builder -> Create Page**. The master report shows customer orders (`ORDERS` table). The detail report shows the products that the customer ordered (`ORDER_ITEMS` table).

[image]

The master report (`ORDERS` table) has a date column (`ORDER_DATE`). In the report, the date column header is a **datepicker item** in which you can select an dropdown of past dates to sort the report.

[image]

I would like to include another report region at the bottom of this page to show the total dollars from the range. (Ex: if a user selects **Last Month**, then I want the report to show the sum of the total dollars from last month).

[image]

I've been able to do this in a custom page that I've built using by adding two **datepicker items**.

[image]

However, in a 'pre-built' **Master Detail** page using **App Builder**, I don't see the **datepicker** item to manipulate.

[image]

How can I grab the **datepicker item** and access it's functions (to query results for the additional report) and dynamic actions (region refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That column header is not a page item, it is the native column filter functionality from the interactive grid component. It's not possible to "Grab it and put it elsewhere". There are a couple of options.

1. Create a separate date picker item in a region above the report where the user selects the from date or range and refresh master region when values change. Make sure to disable column filtering then in the interactive grid region.
2. Another option is to add a dynamic sum at the bottom of the report. That is described [here](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/interactive-grid-dynamic-sum-in-a-total-row-8646). Or calculate the sum and put it in a page item. The post above references an example in the interactive grid cookbook that you can use.